# OpenXML - Wordprocessing - Table Cell commands

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

```
  cell = (TableCell)cell;
  Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
  Run run = p.Elements<Run>().FirstOrDefault();
  RunProperties runProps = new RunProperties();
  Bold bold = new Bold();
  runProps.Append(bold);
  run.AppendChild(new RunProperties(runProps));
```

I have commands stored in enumeration and abstract classes mapping these commands from an abstract Cell to an OpenXml cell. These commands include: Bold, Underline, Italic, Left Align, etc. I am looking to modify the cell run without having a ChildAppend child collision error that is typically thrown when appending an invalid child. What would be the best approach? Modify the paragraph properties of the cell or the run properties?

This may just be my misunderstanding of what OpenXml looks like under the hood and which attributes are openly append-able / need to be only created once.

Comment: Your problem description isn't really clear - an example of "good" vs. "Bad" code might help a bit. It's also not clear what you mean by "modify the cell run" - whether you mean text and formatting or only formatting. If you want to see what Open XML looks like "under the hood", use the Open XMl SDK Productivity Tool to look at the actual XML. You can also create a document with the starting point, save it, make the kind of change you're interested in save to a different name, then use the Tool's "Compare" functionality to see how it "should" be done.

Comment: Reading the ECMA documentation might also give some insight.